# Stylehatch's 'Photoset-Grids' with 'View.js' Not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tumblr

So I am using stylehatch's 'Photoset-grids' plugin without error on my tumblr theme!
I have it setup like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {                
        $('.photoset-grid').photosetGrid({
            gutter: '5px',
            highresLinks: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my html for the photosets block is:

```
{block:Photoset}
    <div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}">
        {block:Photos}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"/>
        {/block:Photos}
    </div>
    {block:Caption}
        {Caption}
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

It works wonderfully!

The problem started when I added view.js. You see, view.js requires every image to be wrapped in a link, but wrapping the images in the "photoset-grid" div somehow brakes the plugin.

I updated my html to this:

```
{block:Photoset}
    <div class="photoset-grid" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}">
        {block:Photos}
            <a href="{PhotoURL-500}" class="view" rel="{PostID}">
                <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"/>
            </a>
        {/block:Photos}
    </div>
    {block:Caption}
        {Caption}
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

And View.js works, but the grids are all messed up and mis-aligned. (I think that the grid plugin is looking for images in the "photoset-grid" div but is only finding links, or something like that)

Any idea what I could do to make it work right? Here is a live demo of my site:
http://test-theme-one.tumblr.com/